# npm install on vagrant virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, npm

Seem to be having A LOT of trouble figuring this one out, but I'm attempting to use vagrant and provision a server that uses node / npm to install dependencies.  My setup is:

- ubuntu 12.04 host (old dev environment)
- ubuntu 12.04 guest (created via vagrant)
- using shell provisioner to setup my server (php 5.3, apache, mysql)
- all is good, everything installs, UNTIL I get to the `npm install` command

In my case, npm install *seems* to install everything (lots of terminal output, etc...).  The next line in the provisioning script does `grunt someTask` to which I get "grunt command not found".  So even though `npm install` appeared to install everything in reality it didn't.

In researching, it seems to be an issue with virtualbox and symlinks in a shared folder.  I've added:

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
  vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
```

end

which seems to have no effect.  I also attempted install with the `--no-bin-links` flag, again, seems to have no effect.  Any ideas how I can get npm to install my project dependencies properly?  Thanks so much for any input.

**EDIT:**

This gist, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b760fdfa9c204c24424b is the output I get when I run vagrant up.  As you can see it appears as if everything is installing, yet, when I ssh into the box, or even from the provisioning script, I can not run "grunt" as it says it's not installed.  There is a node_modules in my repo after the `npm install --no-bin-links` is complete.

Comment: could you please provide some logs?

Comment: Hi @neutrinus, this gist is the output of the provision.sh script that runs when I vagrant up. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b760fdfa9c204c24424b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `grunt` as it seems it is not being installed by your provisioning script.

To install it globally run this command:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

You can either run it manually or add it to your provisioning script.

Comment: grunt is listed as a dependency in my package.json file.  When running npm install this should be installed, yes?  Also it works fine when I just npm install on my local machine, so I know the package.json file is configured properly.

Comment: but if grunt was installed correctly you shouldn't get `grunt command not found`. Maybe it install non-cli version via package.json, but the deployment script expects global `grunt` (note the `-g` flag in `npm install`). It would also make sense why it is working in your local environment - I would guess you also have grunt installed globally there.

Comment: Hmm, just realized there is a difference between grunt and grunt-cli.  It seems I can't install grunt-cli via package.json, so I moved that inline in the provisioning script, and then run npm install to install all the other dependencies.  It works!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you used the right repository to install NPM?

```
apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I used to install nodejs without this repository and got a lot of troubles, with this repository i can use NPM install free of errors in my Vagrant Virtual Box Using Ubuntu 12.04, try it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Yes, I'm using that PPA for node.  That section of my provisioning script looks like:  `#install node
add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
apt-get update
apt-get install python g++ make nodejs`